# ora 24960 error came when connecting to oracle 10g in c++ using occi

Tags: c++, oracle

Hi i tried to connect oracle 10g in c++ using occi, the environment was created successfully, but when trying to create a connection

ora 24960 came and it said that **the attribute OCI_ATTR_USERNAME is greater than the maximum allowable length of 255**

I am very new to c++ and occi so please help me in that issue

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

"Are you using Instant Client by chance? I believe there are some issues when using Instant Client due to the oraocci10d.lib not being shipped as part of the Instant Client package. I just checked my 11g Instant Client directory and the oraocci11d.lib file is not included so I think it is missing from 10g as well."

Quoted from here: [Oracle forum](http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=3149026&#3149026)

If above doesn't help, could you please post some code that reproduces this error on your system? What are your connections setting (tnsnames.ora)?

Kind regards